# How do I load all results on a webpage that uses "scroll to load more" techniques?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, automation

On the platform that I'm focusing on, I'm trying to load the results of followers that are following a specific user. Currently it only loads 20 results at a time when viewing a specific user's followers. The only way to load more results is to scroll down. With automation using Selenium with Python, this would be fairly simple, but very time consuming. By hand it's not too bothersome if the user in question has less than 100 followers, but tiresome when it reaches thousands of followers.

Is there a way to load more results at once? I'm trying to find ways through XHR headers and requests to see if there's a way to load more at once but I can't figure it out. Essentially, I want to speed up the process of scrolling for hours to load more results of followers on a specific social media platform. The goal is to load them all at once to scrape the usernames for a database.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I haven't used any code yet for this. I'm unsure how to even go about it. I wanted to figure out how to do it by hand before using automation to do so.

Comment: Since you know how to automate with Selenium and that's a symple job, that's not a selenium question.

Comment: @osfresia I tagged Selenium in the post because I plan on moving to an automated way of loading all of the said results once I figure out how to do it manually.